# Get array value at specific index and column

Tags: php, arrays

Using php, I have populated an array with some data from a .dat-file. It looks like this:

```
7522126 0   0   0   0   0   0   -419.795    -186.24 1852.86 0.134695    -0.995462   -2.53153
7825452 0   0   0   0   0   0   -419.795    -186.24 1852.86 0.134695    -0.995462   -2.53153
8073799 0   0   0   0   0   0   -345.551    -140.711    1819.04 -0.0220266  -0.85992    -2.29598
```

The values are each seperated by a tab.

To get every value from a specific column, e.g the 9th column, I've been doing the following:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value[9];
}
```

However, I want to be able to get the 9th column only at a specific index. For example the 9th column at index 1. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: means you want 9 index value become 1st index value and 1st will be go to 9th. am i right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
echo $values[1][9];
```

should work.